# Swift Charts create multi label marker

Tags: ios, swift, charts

I have created a marker using the standart file of Charts "BalloonMarker" and have this chart:

```
let marker:BalloonMarker = BalloonMarker(
     color: #colorLiteral(red: 0.07450980392, green: 0.1960784314, blue: 0.2666666667, alpha: 1), 
     font: UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 12)!, 
     textColor: UIColor.white, insets: UIEdgeInsets(top: 7.0, left: 7.0, bottom: 7.0, right: 7.0))
marker.minimumSize = CGSize(width: 75.0, height: 60.0)
chartView.marker = marker
```

[image]

This is the array containing my information:

```
let a: [Double] = [2.5, 2.0, 2.6, 1.8, 0.5, 2.3, 2.5, 2.6, 1.8, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, 3.7, 3.2]
```

How  change the label and add + 5 labels with data like below?

[image]

Comment: BaloonMarker is MarkerImage type class, so need to modify or customize the class according to ur need, the current class only have single label to display. You need to extend its rect size and add multiple label in draw rect method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a `BalloonMarker`, it would be better to use a `MarkerView` for what you are trying to do. You can also create a subclass of [MarkerView](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/blob/master/Source/Charts/Components/MarkerView.swift) and customize it however you wish to for a custom layout.

1. Create a subclass of `MarkerView`, say `DemoMarker`
2. Add the marker to your chart

`let demoMarker: DemoMarker = DemoMarker.viewFromXib()
demoMarker.chartView = yourChartView
yourChartView.marker = demoMarker`